# How can I remove dns server by command line on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop?

Tags: networking, command-line

OK. I install a Server with Ubuntu 20.04. I set the Network with IP:192.168.200.15 Netmask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.200.1 and DNS: 192.168.200.1. Now I need to change DNS: to 192.168.200.50. With command `nmcli connection modify eno2 +ipv4.dns 192.168.200.50` I can add DNS. Now I see both 192.168.200.1 and 192.168.200.50 with command `nmcli connection show eno2 | grep ipv4.dns`. Since I can not get to the server right now, I would like to know how can I remove the DNS: 192.168.200.1 with command line.

Comment: "Remove the other one?" It's really unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question and pretend we don't know anything - because we don't!

Comment: OK. I install a Server with Ubuntu 20.04. I set the Network with IP:192.168.200.15 Netmask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.200.1 and DNS: 192.168.200.1. Now I need to change DNS: to 192.168.200.50. With command nmcli connection modify eno2 +ipv4.dns 192.168.200.50 I can add DNS. Now I see both 192.168.200.1 and 192.168.200.50 with command nmcli connection show eno2 | grep ipv4.dns. Since I can not get to the server right now, I would like to know how can I remove the DNS: 192.168.200.1 with command line.

Comment: Can you please edit your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just like always. I finally found my answer. Instead of nmcli connection modify eno2 +ipv4.dns 192.168.200.50, I used nmcli connection modify eno2 ipv4.dns 192.168.200.50. Without the + symbol, it over writes everything instead of adding it. I don't know why I didn't see that early.